# Accessing the Extended ASCII Character Set from 0xF000 to 0xF0FF using ncursesw in Raspbian Linux

Tags: linux, ncurses, curses

I'm writing an application for the non-GUI text terminal in Raspian Linux in C++ using the ncursesw library.  I found out by accident that if you print *anything* with mvwaddch using A_ALTCHARSET (e.g. `mvwaddch(stdscr, 1, 1, A_ALTCHARSET | 65);`), then the entire Extended ASCII character set (0 - 255) becomes available to mvadd_wch starting from index 0xF000.

It doesn't look like 0xF000 is an official mapping for the UTF-8 locale that my terminal is configured for.  Somehow the ncursesw library triggers the system to load up these characters.

How is this done?  Is there a way to load up this character set without first writing junk data using A_ALTCHARSET?

It may be enough for my purposes to use a `mvwaddch(stdscr, 0, 0, A_ALTCHARSET);` to print a null character when the program initializes.  But I would still like to know what is happening behind the scenes here.

For reference, this is the character set I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean for "Extended ASCII Charset"? In any case the range E000–F8FF is for private use. And it is not "loading". Possibly the font has already such characters

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, I added a picture of the character set to the post.  The characters do already exist scattered across the various UTF-8 ranges, but not until that A_ALTCHARSET bit is used.  I was surprised to find them all arranged in order like this.  I've been using this character set for several decades now, so it's helpful to have them all in order.  If this is a known feature of the ncurses library then I can use it, but I would hate to write a program that depends on a feature that may disappear in the next release of the library.

Comment: The values generated by OR-ing in `A_ALTCHARSET` doesn't mean anything outside of ncurses. It has to translate them into the correct Unicode characters for your terminal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, true, but ncurses is doing something behind the scenes to load this character set.  I didn't exist in the system until after the call was made, and then the character set persisted after the process was shut down.

Comment: BTW, it is code page 437, used mostly in US. West Europe used cp850 if I remember correctly. I think it just for convenience, for legacy use. I do not remember what charset is using Raspberry (it may be hardware coded).

Comment: @TreyTomes [More information on code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  More than likely, that character set was chosen because it was the dominant one in use at the time Linux came about.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi In old DOS systems the character set was loaded at 0xFFA6E.  Code page 437 contains the only characters actually implemented in UTF-8 in the terminal.  It would be interesting to know whether or not the character set is built in to the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ncurses has to support certain terminal descriptions which send "8-bit" codes for the alternate character set feature.  The Linux console happens to be a commonly-used case.  There's a few places in the source-code which you would find helpful to understand, e.g., in the [update-code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/e501ea9108bdf27409055551c5a0ae126a490475/ncurses/tty/tty_update.c#L246).

```
/*
 * If the character falls into any of these special cases, do
 * not force the result to a blank:
 *
 * a) it is printable (this works around a bug in wcwidth()).
 * b) use_legacy_coding() has been called to modify the treatment
 *    of codes 128-255.
 * c) the acs_map[] has been initialized to allow codes 0-31
 *    to be rendered.  This supports Linux console's "PC"
 *    characters.  Codes 128-255 are allowed though this is
 *    not checked.
 */
```

The Linux console has no special knowledge of PC-character sets (the [console_codes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) manual page mentions only UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1), but the **`showconsolefont`** command uses a Linux ioctl to allow it to print a table of 256 codes, which depending upon the **font** which has been loaded, will match some PC code-page (see my answer to [*Why does **`showconsolefont`** have different output in **`tmux`**?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321784/why-does-showconsolefont-have-different-output-in-tmux)).